# Program to find the Set of Subsets using Iteration in Java. Issue: Two ArrayLists happen to share the same Address. Help to Debug

Tags: java, memory, arraylist, data-structures, subset

**Intro**: Below is the program to find the set of subsets, using iteration, in Java.

**Issue**: The `ans` is also getting updated with the new value when only `ansCopy` is attempted to update.

For example, I take `a` value as {5,4,6}. In the first iteration, 5 gets appended in the first inner array list of `ansCopy`. But to the surprise the first inner array list of `ans` also gets appended by 5.

Maybe, the two `ArrayList` `ans` and `ansCopy` happen to share the same address.

**Requirement**: Can someone explain why this is happening and help me to debug it!

```java
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> > subsetUsingIteration2(int[] a) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> > ans=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> >();
    ans.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); 
    // ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> > ans={{}};
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> > ansCopy=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> >();
    // ArrayList<Integer> ansCopy={};
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
      ansCopy.addAll(ans);      
      for(int j=0; j<ansCopy.size(); j++) 
        ansCopy.get(j).add(a[i]);
      ans.addAll(ansCopy);
      ansCopy.clear();      
    }
    return ans;
  }
```

**Attempts**:
When I take a={5,4,6} as the input, I am supposed to get this output

> [[], [5], [4], [6], [5,4], [4,6], [5,6], [5,4,6]]

instead I get this output

> [[5, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6], [5, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6], [5, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6],
> [5, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6], [5, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6], [5, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6],
> [5, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6], [5, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6]]

Tried to find the memory addresses of those two variables but could not find them.

Comment: Try running the code in a debugger.  Set a breakpoint early. This will pause execution at the breakpoint. Then, run the code one-step-at-a-time. At each step, monitor the variables.

Answer (score 0):

In each step, you should copy each of the lists inside `ans`, append a new digit from array `a` to it and add that new list to `ans` again.

You have started correctly. But, it is better to use List instead of array list as the reference type.

```
List<List<Integer> > ans = new ArrayList<>();
ans.add(new ArrayList<>());
```

And, in the for loop:

1. Copy each element from the `ans`.
2. Add the new element from array `a` which to create a new subset.
3. Add the new subset created which is represented by `inner` to the `ans`

   ```
   for (int elem : a) {
       int n = ans.size();
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           // copy each element from the `ans` which is already populated.
           List<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<>(ans.get(i));
           // Add the new elment from array `a` which is basically a new 
           // subset
           inner.add(elem);
           // Add the new subset represented by `inner` to the ans
           ans.add(inner);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @hermit for providing an alternate solution. But can me find out that why a lot this issue this happening with my code.

Comment: @PrashantKumarSingh This statement ansCopy.get(j).add(a[i]) will modify ansCopy and ans both. So, it is leading to unexpceted behavior. So, instead of ansCopy.addAll(ans) you can copy each item of ans into a new arraylist, add item from array to it and finally add it to ans. Basically, what we are doing is the same approach. It is just that you have made few incorrect assumptions and the code is not working as expected.